# Is it possible to copy files to QEMU image without running QEMU?

Tags: qemu

I am running CI with QEMU. Before I start to run tests, I copy files into QEMU by running it, waiting until it finishes booting, copying the files from the HOST into the QEMU image, and then closing the session (and the files are in the image). After that, I start running my tests...
Is it possible to copy files to QEMU image without running QEMU and wait for it to boot?

Comment: Yes, you can mount your image and copy the files into the mounted filesystem. How — depends on what format your image has and what host OS you're using.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on the target and Ubuntu 18 on the host.

Answer (score 0):

found an answer in this link
https://gist.github.com/shamil/62935d9b456a6f9877b5

Step 1 - Enable NBD on the Host

```
modprobe nbd max_part=8
```

Step 2 - Connect the QCOW2 as network block device

```
qemu-nbd --connect=/dev/nbd0 /var/lib/vz/images/100/vm-100-disk-1.qcow2
```

Step 3 - Find The Virtual Machine Partitions

```
fdisk /dev/nbd0 -l
```

Step 4 - Mount the partition from the VM

```
mount /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt/somepoint/
```

Step 5 - After you done, unmount and disconnect

```
umount /mnt/somepoint/
qemu-nbd --disconnect /dev/nbd0
rmmod nbd
```